# How can I hide the timer at left/top corner of SMPlayer 19.10?

Tags: 20.04, video-player, smplayer

Where in SMPlayer 19.10 under Ubuntu 20.04 can I find a setting to hide the timer at the left/top corner?

Comment: Did you try this, https://old-forum.smplayer.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5405, "Options -> OSD -> Subtitles only."

Comment: No I did not find such menu options. Maybe it referenced old version of smplayer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the menu select *View* > *OSD* then select either of:

> Subtitles only
> Volume + Seek